# How do I install a Java Desktop App and A Tomcat Web App with one installer using Advanced Installer

Tags: java, windows-installer

I have a Java desktop application and a web application using JSPs with an Apache web server. I want to create a single installer using Advanced Installer 10.8. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should create the project like this:

- launch Advanced Installer and go to "**Java -> Tomcat Web Application**" on the start page.
  This will start a wizard that will make it very easy to create the installer for your web app.
- second part, is to add the EXE launcher and file for your desktop app. Here you just need to work in Files and Folders page (select the folder desired or create a new one where you drag and drop the files of your desktop app), and with Java Products page where you need to create a new product (the EXE launcher for your desktop app), then go back to Files and Folders page and create a shortcut for your new EXE launcher, so the users can start your app.

The AI forums have tons of info about [installing web apps with Tomcat](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/search.html?cx=006686361644407349086:yneweleowua&cof=FORID:9&ie=UTF-8&q=tomcat&siteurl=http://www.advancedinstaller.com/), and for the desktop app you have the [tutorial on creating an installer for java desktop applications](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-java.html) has some clues.